# Export to excel for dynamic HTML table

Tags: html, angularjs, excel

I have a HTML view integrated with Angularjs which has a dynamic table.

- There are 15 columns and the user can decide which columns he wants to see. The columns can be hidden.
- Filters can be applied on the data in the table to refine it further. The data is inside an array of objects 'vm.reportData' which changes as the filters are applied.
- At a time, the table shows only 10 rows and the user has to click on next page to view more data.

Is there any way to export the filtered data and only the visible columns into an xls or csv file? I tried to use Javascript and other libraries to do the same but it's returning only 1st 10 rows which are  visible and also shows the HTML in the file too.

[image]

Is there any solution with which I can get all the rows data in a file?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do this by saving the rows into a separate variable, an array or object, and then use a csv export module (from nodejs would be my backend choice)?

Comment: The problem is that i don't have to show the hidden column data. Each cell data has been formatted to show in the HTML. Also, if there are 1000 rows, then i have to run loops to get all the visible rows  and format them again which will take a lot of execution time.

Comment: Visibility of those depends by a css rule, correct?

Comment: There is a dropdown containing all the column name. The user can select as many as he wants.

Comment: are you having check box for each rows ?..

Comment: No. I have added a screenshot of the table. The table is scrollable. And based on the dropdown data columns will be visible/hidden.

Comment: you need to export full table or the selected rows only

Comment: i think you are getting confused between rows and columns. I need all the 'rows' but selected 'columns' should be there in that row.

Comment: Might wanna take a look at ExcelPlus it is a Javascript library that lets you create excel file from data. Don't know if you tried it already or if it meets your requirements, but might be worth taking a look at.